# Where can I read up on the "BLU" convention?

Tags: color, hyperlinks

A course in web design mentioned the "BLU" rules, which covers that visited links should be colored differently. I tried to read more about it online, but was unable to google it. Does anyone know where I can look it up?

Comment: I've never heard of "BLU" rules, and, as you've mentioned, it's not mentioned on google. You should ask your instructor about the terminology as it is certainly not in widespread use.

Comment: You got me curious, what is this BLU thing? Never heard about it, and couln't find anything anywhere. Do you have a link or something?

Comment: Never heard of it either. Many websites use other Link colors. Twitter lets the user pixk which color the minks on their own profile page has. I'm currently writing a website where I dont want this rule to apply because my footer is already red and i dont want the links on to be also red of visited

Comment: Thank you all for your input. I'll ask the professor; it's strange that he used this weird term, even multiple times in his class.

Comment: @mafu To answer your question in your flag, this was closed because you aren't being clear in your question.  Simply stating an acronym for something which wouldn't be clear to most users makes the question unclear.  However it also is essentially a "find x for me" type question which also isn't allowed.

Comment: I just got the answer, though I cannot add it to a closed question. BLU refers to "Blue/vioLet/Underlined", which looks prettier in German, and was created by Tim Berners-Lee.

Comment: @mafu, Even with that information, the post would be more of a "find x for me post".  However, if you want to know something specific about underlined link colours, you're welcome to ask that as a new question, which should then meet the site's question requirements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From an accessibility point of view regarding the styling of visited links, the following links are good to read up on:

1. http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-UAAG20-Reference-20140925/#sc_131
2. http://webaim.org/blog/wcag-2-0-and-link-colors/

Both provide good examples as to why it's important to style visited links differently.

The first link is a direct reference to the to W3C technical documentation to reference for Guideline 1.3 - Provide highlighting for selection, keyboard focus, enabled elements, visited links. The summary of this guideline is:

> The user can visually distinguish between selected, focused, and enabled items; and recently visited links (1.3.1); with a choice of highlighting options that at least include foreground and background colors, and border color and thickness (1.3.2).

There is additional detail in this documentation regarding intent and examples of how the criterion should be successfully met. For the purposes of this answer (and not drowning you with examples of it being implemented), the following is the intents of each 1.3.1 and 1.3.2 of these guidelines which explain why differentiating visited links is important:

> **1.3.1** - Users need to be able to easily discover web content they can interact with. One effective way to do this is to highlight enabled elements and links (including recently visited links). Highlighted selection and content focus lets people who use keyboard, gesture and speech input know where they are working. On some pages controls may be difficult to discern amid a large amount of other content, or may be styled so the controls are difficult to distinguish from other content. This can be particularly difficult for people with visual impairments, who may not be able to distinguish subtle visual differences. People with some cognitive impairments may have difficulty distinguishing between items with similar or non-standard appearance. Visually distinguishing these items reduces the amount of time or number of commands these groups require to examine a page.
>
> **1.3.2** - Low vision users and users with some cognitive disabilities need control over visual properties to meet their individual needs. These include foreground colors, background colors, and visual borders (with the same configurable range as the operating environment's conventional selection utilities)

Meeting 1.3.1 and 1.3.2 achieve a Level A and Level AA standard respectively (for more information on what Level A, AA & AAA standards mean please visit the following link - http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20/)

The second link I provided is an easier to read format in comparison to the technical documentation from WC3, but both convey the same message of the importance of differentiating visited link colours.

Comment: Might be a good idea to quote some of the key content which answers the question from those links in case they become broken links in the future

Comment: Apologies @DaveHaigh I was in a rush when answering this question. I have elaborated as to what these links were referencing (without copy and pasting pages of technical documentation).

Answer (score 6):

There are plenty of sources online about visited link color, but one credible source is Nielsen Norman Group. Both Jakob Nielsen and Donald Norman have each spent more than 20 years researching user behavior and user experience.

They say:

> People get lost and move in circles when websites use the same link color for visited and new destinations. To reduce navigational confusion, select different colors for the two types of links.

Reference: [Change the Color of Visited Links](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/change-the-color-of-visited-links/)

Meaning you should let the user know if she has been here before to avoid the confusion. This is especially important if you use related content links, which may link to articles in a different view. If you let the user know this is the case, you greatly improve the user experience.

However, this is an article written in 2004, and can be seen as a bit too old. Still I believe this is valid especially in web sites focusing on content. E-commerce sites and advanced web applications may use a different approach.